# Laravel 4 - Hashing same password gives different values

Tags: php, authentication, hash, laravel-4

I am trying to authenticate a user using the `Auth::attempt()` method and it keeps failing, so I eventually ended up with the following code:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['verified'] = Hash::make('1234') . ' ; ' . Hash::make('1234');
return json_encode($arr);
```

and this is the result:

```
{"verified":"$2y$10$V4yXBUcxealfLrzOE\/xAD.sJ8qpNhrMA6K6dENBBXYqaVx1zSETgy ; $2y$10$C9xpOWLTUyfy1KL.Y3Tot.KWADmQYFK\/HAf6uZGGXTKcVh52qHS4m"}
```

As you can see, the first hash gives `$2y$10$V4yXBUcxealfLrzOE\/xAD.sJ8qpNhrMA6K6dENBBXYqaVx1zSETgy` and the second hash gives `$2y$10$C9xpOWLTUyfy1KL.Y3Tot.KWADmQYFK\/HAf6uZGGXTKcVh52qHS4m`

This should have nothing to do with the database even though when storing, I have a 60 character password field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is perfectly fine and also the way it is supposed to work.
Laravel uses [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) for Hashing and is therefore generating a random salt during the hashing process. The salt will be part of the Hash which is why you are getting two different results.

The veryfing algorithm is taking the salt into consideration automatically. This method makes the use of rainbow tables nearly impossible.

It's not a bug, it's extra security with no effort.

Given your example veryfing against both of your hashes will return true:

```
<?php

$hash1 = Hash::make('1234'); // A hash is generated
$hash2 = Hash::make('1234'); // Another hash is generated that differs from the first one

var_dump(Hash::check('1234', $hash1) && Hash::check('1234', $hash2));
```

Although `$hash1` and `$hash2` contain different hashes, veryfing against them with the given base string will evaluate to true.

**The generated hash has a length of 60 characters. So it should be made sure that the column where the hash is stored also has a minimum size of 60 characters**

Comment: But I need to store the hashed password in the database, how do I compare to that? because the password will not always be `1234`. And how can I use this with the `Auth::attempt()` method?

Comment: @user3723418 - The random salt will become part of the resulting hash-value, this salt is extracted from the stored hash-value to verify the entered password, just use `Hash::check()` it does it automatically for you.

Comment: @user3723418 using the Auth::attempt() method is even easier. As soon as you have the hashed salt in your database (correct db design assumed) laravel will automatically check the input against the fields in your database. If there is a password field in the db and a password key in your array you pass to the `Auth::attempt()` method laravel will automatically check against these two values taking the hashing into consideration and then do the session handling.

Comment: But I hashed the password, copied it exactly, put it in the database, then tried again using same password, and it failed.

Comment: Your password field has 60 characters in the database?