# why is the hash-method in the seeder different from the hash-method in the controller? Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hash, laravel-5.1

In my **seeder** I have hashed my code like this :

```
'validCode' => Hash::make('1110578abc')
```

it gives this result in the database :  *$2y$10$GaKhhxrMNCnzr*

When I'm hashing the same code by input in my controller it gives a different value because of the random salt added by Bcrypt.

**Controller :**

```
dd(Hash::make(Input::get('code')));
```

(I typed in 1110578abc in this input field.)

It gives me this value :

*$2y$10$xxVU78CphJEGOOTT1teNY.LeLb7kBjDvP9Npbf1h4.T4HDtuIFD16*

For my application I would like to check if these 2 values match. Does annyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - Hashing same password gives different values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381316/laravel-4-hashing-same-password-gives-different-values)

Comment: In that post they explain why it changes , it is usefull to know. But this still doesn't solve my problem. How can I check if the code from the input matches with the hashed code in my database if they are always different ?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Hash::check()` method. The `check` method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash.
Try:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

[You can read more about Laravel Hashing.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing)

Comment: I had find this before in the laravel documentation , but I noticed that I have used this method in a wrong way before. Trying it again with this method made it work :         if (Hash::check(Input::get('code') , '$2y$10$GaKhhxrMNCnzr'))
       {
            dd('match');
       }
        else
       {
          dd('no match');
       }

Answer (score 0):

Specific code that answers to my post :

```
if (Hash::check(Input::get('code') , '$2y$10$GaKhhxrMNCnzr'))
{ 
    dd('match');
} 
else 
{ 
    dd('no match'); 
}
```

this solves it and returns 'match'.